# Why Do Portrait View Photos Display Horizontally?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, imageview

I am hoping someone can help me fix this issue as I'm a major noob to java and I've tried numerous codes but nothing seems to be working. What happens is when I open up my app in portrait view it display the image in landscape view instead.

However, if I open up app in landscape view and take photo it display in landscape...how it should.

How can I fix this for portrait view as well?

This is main activity java

```
package com.makingmemad.apk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String mFileUri;
    private final Context mContext = this;

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnbutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnbutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = createPictureFile();
                mFileUri = uri.getEncodedPath();
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    @
    Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (mFileUri != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("filepath", mFileUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == 1) { // image
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == 2) { // video
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public Uri createPictureFile() {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File pictureDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            pictureDir = new File(pictureDir, "MyApp");

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!pictureDir.exists()) {
                if (!pictureDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("user", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            //Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String fileName = pictureDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            File imageFile = new File(fileName);

            // Convert to URI and return
            return Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        } else {
            Log.d("user", "No media mounted");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my acitivty_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.MYAPPNAME.apk.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    android:text="LET&apos;S BEGIN"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:text="Before you begin, PLEASE NOTE that this game is intended for entertainment purposes only."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my SecondActivity.java file

```
package com.MYAPPNAME.apk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String filepath = intent.getStringExtra("filepath");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8; // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory         Exception for larger images
        filepath = filepath.replace("file://", ""); // remove to avoid        BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null
        File imgFile = new File(filepath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity_second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context="com.MYAPPNAME.apk.SecondActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my ExifUtil file

```
package com.MYAPPNAME.apk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Build;


public class ExifUtil {



    public Bitmap rotateBitmap(String path) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        return ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(path, myBitmap);
    }


    /**
     * @see http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
     */
    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

            if (orientation == 1) {
                return bitmap;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case 2:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
                default:
                    return bitmap;
            }

            try {
                Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                return oriented;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        try {
            /**
             * if your are targeting only api level >= 5
             * ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
             * orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                Class <? > exifClass = Class.forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
                Constructor <? > exifConstructor = exifClass.getConstructor(new Class[] {
                    String.class
                });
                Object exifInstance = exifConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] {
                    src
                });
                Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt", new Class[] {
                    String.class, int.class
                });
                Field tagOrientationField = exifClass.getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
                String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
                orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance, new Object[] {
                    tagOrientation, 1
                });
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orientation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exif data on the image which tells you the orientation. You have to rotate your image based on the exif data before setting it to your imageview.
Here's code that you can use, use like this

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(String path) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    return ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(path, myBitmap);
}
```

NEW ExifUtil.java file

```
package com.makingmemad.apk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Build;


public class ExifUtil {


    /**
     * @see http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
     */
    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

            if (orientation == 1) {
                return bitmap;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case 2:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
                default:
                    return bitmap;
            }

            try {
                Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                return oriented;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        try {
            /**
             * if your are targeting only api level >= 5
             * ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
             * orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                Class <? > exifClass = Class.forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
                Constructor <? > exifConstructor = exifClass.getConstructor(new Class[] {
                    String.class
                });
                Object exifInstance = exifConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] {
                    src
                });
                Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt", new Class[] {
                    String.class, int.class
                });
                Field tagOrientationField = exifClass.getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
                String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
                orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance, new Object[] {
                    tagOrientation, 1
                });
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orientation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Noev, I am trying to implement this code but I am not sure where to put it in my main activity or second activity ive tried putting it in both but it doesnt seem to change anything. if you can help better understand where it should go that would be the bessssst!:)

Comment: Create a separate class called ExifUtil, it should contain the rotateBitmap method and getExifOrientation. Then use rotateBitmap wherever you need to rotate your bitmap like this imageView.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(imgPath));

Comment: hi noev if you look up top you can see the new ExifUtil class i created and i tried to put this code ImageView.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(imgPath));  above and below the other ImageView imageView code in my SecondActivity.java file but there is always a redline under imgPath and If i change imgPath to filepath then rotateBitmap becomes red:S

Comment: So why don't you hover over the red line which tells you what's the issue?

Comment: i do when i change imgPath to filepath it gives me 4 options, create local variable, field etc. no matter which one i choose then rotateBitmap becomes red when i go over that then it says create method or string and when i do that the whole line you gave me becomes red and says cannot make a static reference to non static refrence. like i said im a noob lol:(

Comment: use like this imageView.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(filepath)); instead of imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

Comment: hey noev sorry i took a hiatus for a bit as i got a virus on my laptop and had to reformat/restart everything from scratch. Ive updated the code to what im using now but i still cant get it to rotate. Ive created a exifutil class and put the other code in as well as you can see but when i use imageView.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(filepath)); in my secondactivity java instead of imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); it gives me an error on rotateBitmap saying no sting create string turns to private static output no photo change to public outputs not photo:S

Comment: I've created a second image view and changed the first one to android:rotation to 90 so now it display properly on portrait but it doesn't on landscape...before i added the rotation 90 it displayed properly on landscape so thats why i tried adding this now below imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); but it only outputs the first imageview each time aka the 90 rotation one

else {

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),   options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Anyone have an idea?